# Combined two meshes, but only one is shaded even though I've added the other to the same texture in UV Editing

Tags: uv, unity

I have combined the body of one character model with the head from another, to make a new character to use in Unity.

I started with the body as the base, and joined the head and combined the meshes with new faces. The head is connected to the body's armature system, and this all works well.

I had hoped to shade the head with the texture that was imported with the body (which was imported as an FBX from Unity). The head was imported as an OBJ.

Once the head was connected, I used the 'UV Editing' window to select faces on the head and move them to the correct colour on the body's texture. This all looked as if it was working, but when I  turned on 'Viewport Shading' no colour was applied to the head.

Here is a picture of what the model looks like after I added the head's faces to the texture:

[image]

Here is a picture of the same model in Edit mode - I have selected two faces, one on the original body, and one on the added head. They are both on the pink square in the texture, but only the face on the body is showing this colour:

[image]

When I export the model to Unity I have the same problem - the head is not coloured (model on the left). However, if I drag the material onto the head in the scene, it gets the colours on the faces. However, they are a different shade to the skin colour on the body, so there is a visible line where the neck meets the head (model on the right):

[image]

I would really appreciate some advice on how I can fix this, so that the textures I try to apply on the head in Blender actually appear, and are visible in Unity. It would be great if I didn't have to apply the material separately to the head in Unity, so the skin tones on the head and body would match up.

One last bit of information that might be relevant - It seems I have two diffuse textures in Blender when I click on the button. I am quite new to Blender, so I don't know if this is important.

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: My guess is you have mapped the UV, but you didn't assign material slots to the polygons, or materials to the material slots.

Comment: Thank you - that was the problem! When I imported the head it came with its own material, which was just a white second material slot. When I deleted this second material slot the head became coloured by the UVs I had set on the primary material slot. Really appreciate the help. All the best for 2022 for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When objects are joined, the resulting material slots is a set union of all material slots, where a slot is considered unique if it points to a unique material. So if you join a body and a head, each having 1 material slot, but they point to different materials, the resulting object will have 2 material slots, and the geometry of the 2nd object (the one being joined to the active object) will be reassigned to the new, 2nd material slot pointing to the material this 2nd object was pointing to. Here the body was the active object and the head was the 2nd object, so the head was reassigned to 2nd material slot and kept its material. Modifying the UV worked just fine, but the geometry of the head had to be reassigned to 1st material slot (or have its material modified so it also uses the image texture the material of the rest of the body uses).